# Increasing _MAX_ROWS_PER_REQUEST in google-bigquery python api

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been using the google-bigquery python api and in the bigquery_client.py file I see there is a global _MAX_ROWS_PER_REQUEST = 1000000.  I have been querying some genomics data and expect responses larger than 1000000 rows.  I tried to increase this variable but I seem to get some strange results.  An example...

```
import bq
.
.
.
q = """ <my query> """
q_result = client.Query(q,destination_table="blah:blah.A")
table_ref = q_result['configuration']['query']['destinationTable']
fields, data = client.ReadSchemaAndRows(table_ref)
print len(data)
```

The length returned is 1050000 which is a list of rows and is less than the exported table blah:blah.A which is ~2.7 million rows in BQ (the correct length).

I then increased _MAX_ROWS_PER_REQUEST = 10000000 and reran the above and got 10015439 as the length!

Comment: It seems you're streaming data into BQ. In that case the next limits apply, which explain the results you see. The limits are server side, so it doesn't matter how much you increase your client variable https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#streaminginserts